# How i can convert coordinates x y from image to longitude/latitude and back?

Tags: algorithm, maps, coordinates, openstreetmap

I have image of the city, how i can get longitude/latitude for the points that i add to the image if i know 3 points like

Point1XRelative = "-18340651.0304568";

Point1YRelative = "14945227.3984772";

Point2XRelative = "-3960915.94162438";

Point2YRelative = "-7933119.6827411";

Point3XRelative = "4901426.10152285";

Point3YRelative = "13585796.8781726";

Point1XWorld = "53.1186547";

Point1YWorld = "29.2392344";

Point2XWorld = "52.6341388";

Point2YWorld = "29.7438198";

Point3XWorld = "53.0900105";

Point3YWorld = "30.0548051";

I have algrithm that can convert only for the plane and when i convert from the long/lat to x y they converts with offset.
Please advice me how i can resolve this problem.

Comment: There are many ways to display maps and aerial photography on a 2D plane. Do you have any indication of which map projection was used in your source material? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection

Comment: I used a map of the little city from OpenStreetMap

Comment: Apparently OpenStreetMap uses WGS 84 for its coordinates: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System#WGS84

Comment: Have you checked this? https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Converting_map_data_between_formats

Comment: So how i can get long/lat from the map if i used little piece of all map?

Comment: I don't want convert map, i want to convert coordinates and save them to database.

Answer (score 1):

It also depends on the zoom level. I think you will find what you need [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames).